# What impact has the Chinese Government had on Chinese Buddhism so far?

Tags: chinese-buddhism

**State Administration for Religious Affairs** (SARA) and the **Buddhist Association of China** are in charge of regulating religion in China.

So far, what effect have they had on doctrine for Chinese (non-vajrayana) Buddhism?

It's already well known that the Chinese government is hostile to the Dalai Lama.

(Also, as a side note, for those skeptical of any government's ability to regulate belief and practice- some percent of American Zen's doctrine and practice can be traced to Meiji era government initiated reforms)

Answer (score 6):

I've seen quite a few news reports that focus on the [huge growth of Christianity in China](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/asia/china/10776023/China-on-course-to-become-worlds-most-Christian-nation-within-15-years.html) so naively I would have expected that this would now have overtaken Buddhism. However [this report](https://www.purdue.edu/newsroom/research/2010/100726T-YangChina.html) states that

> The growth of Christianity is impressive, but Buddhist growth is
>   extraordinary, especially with the country's history of official
>   ideology of atheism

The figures are

- 18% identify as Buddhist
- 15% identify as Atheist
- 3.2% identify as Christian

Considering the vigorous supression during the cultural revolution (all monasteries closed, lands confiscated) it's notable that Buddhism has remained a substantial religion within China. However the attitudes of the Chinese authorities does appear to have softened and [Buddhist are seen as a source of societal good](http://www.china.org.cn/english/China/193520.htm). The Chinese government is clearly still very capable of suppressing religious movements (e.g. [Falun Gong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Falun_Gong)) and cultures (Tibetan) it finds threatening. Fortunately Buddhism doesn't appear to currently be a focus for this suppression.

As a reference note: This is a summary of the section on Buddhism in China from An [Introduction to Buddhism](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/418423.An_Introduction_to_Buddhism) by Peter Harvey (pp 409 - 410 in my copy).